# How to simply footcite with biblatex

Tags: citing

I would like to cite so that the reference shows up in the footer and in a bibliography, with the number of the reference in the text. I tried to do so with the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}

This is the text from some book. \footcite{lit1}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{lit1} Author, \textit{Title}, publisher, location, year.
  \end{thebibliography}
    
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the footnote says "lit1" instead of "Author, Title, ..."

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are better off using an external `.bib` file for the publications and processing with `biber`.  Then you can specify an `authoryear` style.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SE! The problem is that you are mixing two different ways of managing citations and bibliography. One is to use `\cite{}` etc. and `thebibliography`. The other is to use `biblatex` with a database of bibliography entries and `\printbibliography`.

Here's one way of doing it which uses `biblatex/biber` with an external `.bib` file of entries. (The `filecontents` environment just creates the external `.bib` file.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{lit1,
    author      =   {Author, A. N.},
    title       =   {Title},
    publisher   =   {Publisher},
    address     =   {Location},
    year        =   {1066}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This is the text from some book. \footfullcite{lit1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: biblatex with full citation in footnote]

This is just for purposes of demonstration: you wouldn't normally want a full citation in the footnote and a separate bibliography. Although I have seen undergraduate submission requirements which actually demanded just this.

Another way, As [Andrew Swann suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242110/how-to-simply-footcite-with-biblatex#comment575807_242110) is to use

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

with the `\footcite{lit1}` which would give

[image: author-year]

Or you can use `\footfullcite{}` and simply remove the `\printbibliography` command if you don't need a separate bibliography.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response, it was very helpful! I copied your first code, but still have only "lit1" in the footer. I read that in order to get the correct output, i have to run first Latex, then Biber, then Latex twice. But I don't get how to do this in TexnicCenter, as it has no command line.

Comment: @Janine I don't know TexnicCenter specifically but there should be options which allow you to configure the commands which are run when you typeset. It might be worth compiling from the command line first, just to test, outside your editor. Once you know it works, you can then try to figure out how to configure the editor.

Comment: It now worked after I changed the line \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}  to \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

Comment: @Janine That will work. But it is not a great solution because there are features of `biblatex` which require `biber`. So you will probably want to figure out how to use it sooner rather than later.