# How to create a citation in the bibliography corresponding to every footnote?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, footnotes

I'm pretty new to this whole thing, so forgive if this is a stupid question. The only thing I've figured out how to do so far is use `\footnote` to create a footnote which I use as a short version of the long citation. However, this doesnt create an entry in the bibliography.

How can I create a new entry for every footnote I create? I am using TeXstudio.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Would you consider using `biblatex`?  It has a `\footcite` command.

Comment: Relative https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/242110/120578 (just to see how it works in some examples. Also you could remove the TeXStudio part of your question because it doesn't have a relation with the content of your question)

Comment: No one here asks stupid questions... at most you'll find questions that are duplicated :-) Again welcome.